# Script added onto the header.php not loading on some pages, but displays on all pages once logged in to wp-dashboard

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, zendesk

I m adding the following script(zendesk chat widget) on the header.php - in the wordpress website domain.com, in two ways neither works. Chat widget only displayed on all pages  if we are loggedin to wordpresss, Otherwise it would be displayed on some inner pages eg: domain.com/some-inner-pages

First script I added looks like this

```
<script id="ze-snippet" src="https://static.zdassets.com/ekr/snippet.js?key=<key>"> 

</script>
```

Then checked domain.com and it didnt work but if i go domain.com/some-inner-pages it would work, also it would work if I login as admin.

The second try was

```
<script>
  function loadZendeskWidget() {
      var script = document.createElement('script');
      script.type = 'text/javascript';
      script.id = 'ze-snippet';
      script.async = true;
      script.src = 'https://static.zdassets.com/ekr/snippet.js?key=<key>';
      document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
  };
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    loadZendeskWidget(); 
    console.log("test");

</script>
```

Still the same behavior as the first attempt.

Is there anyway I can debug this or fix this? Thanks for any help

header.php file

```
<!doctype html>

<html <?php language_attributes(); ?> class="no-js">
<head>

<!-- Meta Tags -->
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

<?php

$options = get_nectar_theme_options();

if ( ! empty( $options['responsive'] ) && $options['responsive'] == 1 ) { ?>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0" />
<?php } else { ?>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=1200" />
<?php } ?>  

<!--Shortcut icon-->
<?php if ( ! empty( $options['favicon'] ) && ! empty( $options['favicon']['url'] ) ) { ?>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo esc_url( nectar_options_img( $options['favicon'] ) ); ?>" />
<?php }

wp_head();

if ( ! empty( $options['google-analytics'] ) ) {
    echo $options['google-analytics'];}
?>
 <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-154156568-1"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-154156568-1');
</script>
<!-- Start of  Zendesk Widget script -->

<script>
  function loadZendeskWidget() {
      var script = document.createElement('script');
      script.type = 'text/javascript';
      script.id = 'ze-snippet';
      script.async = true;
      script.src = 'https://static.zdassets.com/ekr/snippet.js?key=XX';
      document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
  };
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    loadZendeskWidget(); 
    console.log("test");

</script>
<!--<script id="ze-snippet" src="https://static.zdassets.com/ekr/snippet.js?key=XX"> 

</script> -->
<!-- End of  Zendesk Widget script -->
</head>

<?php

global $post;
global $woocommerce;

$nectar_header_options = nectar_get_header_variables();

?>

<body <?php body_class(); nectar_body_attributes(); ?>>

<?php

nectar_hook_after_body_open();

if ( $nectar_header_options['theme_skin'] == 'material' ) {
    echo '<div class="ocm-effect-wrap"><div class="ocm-effect-wrap-inner">';
}

if ( $nectar_header_options['n_boxed_style'] ) {
    echo '<div id="boxed">';
}

nectar_page_trans_markup();

get_template_part( 'includes/partials/header/secondary-navigation' );

get_template_part( 'includes/partials/header/header-space' );

?>

<div id="header-outer" <?php nectar_header_nav_attributes(); ?>>

    <?php

    if ( empty( $options['theme-skin'] ) || ( ! empty( $options['theme-skin'] ) && $nectar_header_options['theme_skin'] != 'ascend' && $nectar_header_options['header_format'] != 'left-header' ) ) {
        get_template_part( 'includes/header-search' );
    }

    get_template_part( 'includes/partials/header/header-menu' );


    if ( ! empty( $options['enable-cart'] ) && $options['enable-cart'] == '1' && $nectar_header_options['theme_skin'] != 'material' ) {

        if ( $woocommerce ) {
            echo nectar_header_cart_output();
        }
    }

    ?>


</div><!--/header-outer-->

<?php

if ( ! empty( $options['enable-cart'] ) && $options['enable-cart'] == '1' ) {
      get_template_part( 'includes/partials/header/woo-slide-in-cart' );
}

if ( $nectar_header_options['theme_skin'] == 'ascend' || $nectar_header_options['header_format'] == 'left-header' ) {
    if ( $nectar_header_options['header_search'] != 'false' ) {
        get_template_part( 'includes/header-search' ); }
}

if ( $nectar_header_options['mobile_fixed'] != '1' ) {
    get_template_part( 'includes/partials/header/classic-mobile-nav' );
}

?>

<div id="ajax-content-wrap">

<?php
if ( $nectar_header_options['side_widget_area'] == '1' && $nectar_header_options['side_widget_class'] == 'fullscreen' ) {
    echo '<div class="blurred-wrap">';
}
```

Here's the screenshots of header

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you get any console errors?

Comment: No. I double checked , The console log “ test “won’t be displayed on home page either

Comment: Can you post the header.php with the script that isn’t working?

Comment: i have updated the question with header.php code

Comment: Can you see the script tags (for Zendesk) on the page when viewing the source code in the browser?

Comment: Hey Mikerojas, yes i was not able to see the zendesk script in the header file when the widget is not shown . but when its shown (in innerpages) we can see the zendesk script.. so its not even loading on homepages and few inner pages,

 one more thing i tried - i duplicated the homepage to another url and checked if the widget loaded and it did. (not sure why )

Comment: @NaveenDINUSHKA when you visit site root `domain.com`, right click and hit *View Source*; do you see the script code at the top head code as you have it? also, which `header.php` file are you trying to change, where is it located?

Comment: Hey @ChristosLytras I have updated the questions with the screenshots..one screenshot with the script tag that is displayed on domain.com/sub and the other with the screenshot of header file domain.com

Comment: How is the home page created? is it WordPress page and assigned as homepage or is it home.php file. secondly is there any possibility home is loading different header file?

Comment: Are you using any cache? Cache can also be the reason, can you change browser ?

Comment: I would clear your browser cache, sounds a lot like somekind of cache issue. Also try a different browser or different computer even.

Comment: Why is the snippet commented out? <!--<script id="ze-snippet" src="https://static.zdassets.com/ekr/snippet.js?key=XX"> 
</script> --> Also agree with others that you may need to make sure your theme even uses... You might try instead loading the script via wp_head function, the WordPress qeueue, or script-insertion plugin.

Answer (score 0):

- Did you try to move the script to the footer?
- Did you try to include a downloaded/local version of the script with eg.

  `wp_enqueue_script( 'script', get_template_directory_uri() .
  '/js/script.js', array ( 'jquery' ), 1.1, true);`

  in your
  functions.php to include the script?
- Did you test different browsers (disable all plugins, incognito mode)?
- Is any  white/blacklisting going on (configuration zendesk) or blocking from external scipt loading?
- Is the header.php from home the same as sub or is there any chance, that another header.php is loaded?

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding zendesk chat widget then add the embed script in `header.php` file between the page's head tags.

You can paste it either right after the opening `<head>` tag or right before the closing `</head>`.

```
<!-- Start of  Zendesk Widget script -->

<script id="ze-snippet" src="https://static.zdassets.com/ekr/snippet.js?key=<key>"></script>

<!-- End of  Zendesk Widget script -->
```